# Netlify not showing CSS for TailwindCSS website

Tags: css, netlify, tailwind-css

I'm trying to deploy my tailwind site to Netlify. I've been able to deploy it but it only comes out as plain html, no css. My guess is that its because the styles.css is in a src folder but I'm not very sure.
I used tailwind without PostCSS so that could also be a problem.
Any help is appreciated;
Github: https://github.com/JojoDuke/Insure-LandingPage-Design
Site-preview: https://naughty-ptolemy-d0f425.netlify.app/

Comment: Your resources (JS, CSS, etc..) seem to be 404ing on https://naughty-ptolemy-d0f425.netlify.app/ (check the `Network` tab in dev tools). Did you add them to the Netlify server?

Comment: I deployed everything through github

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `link` tags [in your HTML](https://github.com/JojoDuke/Insure-LandingPage-Design/blob/master/public/index.html#L7) aren't pointing to the same location as the output of your `tailwindcss` [build command](https://github.com/JojoDuke/Insure-LandingPage-Design/blob/5b170a2152a7b3b1aff16e60609f9109b8dd6f2d/package.json#L11), causing the CSS to not be pulled through.

Try recloning your repo from scratch, and running the build command you put in your netlify settings, and seeing whether that generates the file in the right location, then update the HTML to match that location.